# Trying to show card details when a user clicks on a card but receiving "not defined" error for the props I am passing in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do not understand the problem. I am trying to make an app where the user is given a list of reviews and when they click on one, they are redirected to a page that shows details of that single review. Here is my ReviewCard.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { reviews } from '../data';
import StarRatings from 'react-star-ratings';
import './Review.css';  

 const ReviewCard= ({ review }) => {
  return (  
    <div class="card-deck">
      {reviews.map((review) => {
        return (
         <div class="card">
          <div key={review.id}>
            <h4 class="card-title">{review.place}</h4>
            <StarRatings
                rating={review.rating}
                starRatedColor="gold" 
                starDimension="20px"
                />
            <div class="card-body">{review.content}</div>
            <div class="card-footer">{review.author} - {review.published_at}</div> 
            
      </div>
      </div>
        );
      })}
      </div> 
          );
      };
  
export default ReviewCard;
```

and my ReviewCollection.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReviewCard from './ReviewCard';

class ReviewCollection extends React.Component {

    goToDetails = (review) => {
        localStorage.setReview('selectedReview', review);
        this.props.history.push('/details');
      };

      render() {
          return (
            <div onClick={() => this.goToDetails(review)}>
                <div className='card-collection'>
                    {this.props.reviews.data
                    .filter((review, idx) => idx < 24)
                    .map((review) => (
                     <ReviewCard key={review.id} review={review} 
                     />
                    ))}
            </div>
        </div>
          )
      }
}

export default ReviewCollection;
```

I am receiving an error from the Review Collection component saying that "Review" is not defined. I do not understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

`<div onClick={() => this.goToDetails(review)}>` Here, you are sending `review` but its not defined anywhere.

I think you need to include your onClick function inside the `.map()` function

```
{this.props.reviews.data
.filter((review, idx) => idx < 24)
.map((review) => (
  <div onClick={() => this.goToDetails(review)}>
    <ReviewCard key={review.id} review={review} />
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: Thank you - the problem is once I do that, I now get this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" ... it seems it now does not know what "reviews" is either

Comment: We haven't changed much of the logic. This error should also have been there before this code change

Comment: yeah before it could not read filter of undefined now it cannot read data of undefined, so it seems to basically be the same problem...not sure what I am doing wrong here, or why reviews is undefined

Comment: What is inside `reviews` Cant it be imported from here `import { reviews } from '../data';` ??

Comment: Yes when I try importing it into that file with that line I get the same error and my terminal tells me "Line 3:10:  'reviews' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars". Not sure why it is saying it is never used?

Comment: Thats just an warning. We can run code with that warning too

Comment: Oh okay I solved that error actually, by changing the code to ```{reviews.filter```

Comment: yes indeed, that error has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReviewCard from './ReviewCard';
import { reviews } from '../data';
import {reactLocalStorage} from 'reactjs-localstorage';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

class ReviewCollection extends React.Component {

    goToDetails = (review) => {
        reactLocalStorage.set('selectedReview', review);
       browserHistory.push('/details');
      };

      render() {
          return (
                <div className='card-collection'>
                    {reviews
                    .filter((review, idx) => idx < 24)
                    .map((review) => (
                     <div onClick={() => this.goToDetails(review)}>
                     <ReviewCard key={review.id} review={review} />
                      </div>
                    ))}
            </div>
          )
      }
}

export default ReviewCollection;
```